# django-allauth include twitter email on sociallogin extra_data

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I was able to look at this [feature](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/1342) and they say in order to include the email of a user from twitter i need to set

`SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True`

Still not working, then i did

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    ...
    'twitter': {
        'SCOPE': ['email'],
    },
}
```

Still got `sociallogin.account.extra_data['email'] KeyError` on twitter account login.

This logic is done in `pre_social_login` signal

```
@receiver(pre_social_login)
def pre_social_login_(sender, request, sociallogin, **kwargs):
    email = sociallogin.account.extra_data['email']
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with my settings the only thing is you have to check the Additional Permission category in Permission tab of your twitter app.

[image]

Of course this requires the privacy policy and term of services under the Settings tab of your application

[image]

Twitter has a strict rule of implementing social auth to every app.